# Get the currently saved object in a view in Django

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I has a Django view which is accessed through an AJAX call. It's a pretty simple one — all it does is simply pass the request to a form object and save the data. Here's a snippet from my view:

```
form = AddSiteForm(request.user, request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    obj = form.save(commit=False)
    obj.user = request.user
    obj.save()
    data['status'] = 'success'
    data['html'] = render_to_string('site.html', locals(), context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(data), mimetype='application/json')
```

How do I get the currently saved object (including the internally generated id column) and pass it to the template?

Any help guys?

Mridang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`obj` is the currently saved object (created when you call `form.save`, and `obj.id` is the id.  It's already passed in `locals()`

This all may seem obvious, but it's all I could decipher from your question.

Comment: It worked. I just had to rename the obj variable to match that the variable in my template. Cheers!